# build fails at camera_calibration_parsers; how do I recompile with -fPIC

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Linux 4.19.12-301.fc29.x86_64 Fedora 29

When I try to run

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

I get the following error, at package 182 off 237

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'camera_calibration_parsers'
==> Building with env: '/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/camera_calibration_parsers'
==> make -j8 -l8 in '/root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/camera_calibration_parsers'
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 50%] Built target camera_calibration_parsers
[ 75%] Linking CXX shared library /root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/camera_calibration_parsers/lib/python2.7/site-packages/camera_calibration_parsers/camera_calibration_parsers_wrapper.so
[ 87%] Built target convert
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a(from_python.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol 'PyExc_TypeError' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/camera_calibration_parsers_wrapper.dir/build.make:142: /root/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/camera_calibration_parsers/lib/python2.7/site-packages/camera_calibration_parsers/camera_calibration_parsers_wrapper.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:521: CMakeFiles/camera_calibration_parsers_wrapper.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'camera_calibration_parsers': 
  Command '['/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh', 'make', '-j8', '-l8']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /root/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/camera_calibration_parsers && /root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j8 -l8

Command failed, exiting.
```

I am a newbie, and I have not a clue about how to fix it.
Thanks for your help

mario

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319324/build-fails-at-camera_calibration_parsers;-how-do-i--recompile-with--fpic/) by [ml@mariochiari.net](https://answers.ros.org/users/40589/ml@mariochiari.net/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think you actually need to "recompile with -fPIC", as the error suggests. (It suggests that you recompile `libboost_python.a`, but you probably got that library from a precompiled package).

It looks like the linking step for `camera_calibration_parsers_wrapper.so` is trying to create a dynamically linked library, but is linking in a static library: `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libboost_python.a` that can't be used to create a dynamic library. I would focus my debugging effort on determining if there is dynamic version (`.so` instead of `.a`) of that library installed, or if there is a Fedora package that you can install for it. If there's a package that isn't installed, I would try installing it (and then clean your workspace and retry the build from the beginning). If the dynamic library is already installed, or installing it doesn't help, I would go through the cmake documentation to figure out why it was trying to link against the static version instead of the dynamic version.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ml@mariochiari.net](https://answers.ros.org/users/40589/ml@mariochiari.net/) on 2019-03-25**:
Thanks for your reply.
It seems I have

```
/usr/lib64/libboost_python.a
/usr/lib64/libboost_python.so.1.66.0
/usr/lib64/libboost_python3.a
/usr/lib64/libboost_python3.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_python3.so.1.66.0
```

Is there a further Fedora package I am missing? I am not sure how to check what you suggest.
Note, I have been able to install ROS by Docker but I would like to fix above too.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-03-25**:
I would expect to see a `/usr/lib64/libboost_python.so` , so it seems like there is a package missing.
The last RPM-based distro I used was RHEL5, so my rpm search skills are pretty rusty, but it looks like you might be missing `boost-python2-devel` (or some more generic boost devel package that depends on it).

**Comment by [ml@mariochiari.net](https://answers.ros.org/users/40589/ml@mariochiari.net/) on 2019-03-25**:
YES, thanks so much, that installs /usr/lib64/libboost_python.so and fixes it.
Later I needed  bullet-devel too.